# Ghostscript: Stop image rotating when converting PDF to Image

Tags: pdf, rotation, orientation, ghostscript, postscript

I am using Ghostscript `10.02.0` to convert a PDF to a PNG with the following command:

`gs -o ./test.png -dNumRenderingThreads=1 -sDEVICE=png16m -r72 -dLastPage=1 -dFitPage -dDEVICEWIDTHPOINTS=125 -dDEVICEHEIGHTPOINTS=100 -dUseTrimBox -dInterpolateControl=-1 -dTextAlphaBits=4 -dGraphicsAlphaBits=4 ./text.pdf`

The command works and converts the PDF to an image, however if the PDF has a height greater than `dDEVICEHEIGHTPOINTS`, Ghostscript rotates the image. I'm sure that this is because of `-dFitPage` however I need Ghostscript to scale the PDF (whatever size it is) to the dimensions.

I've seen in similar Ghostscript questions that `-dAutoRotatePages=false` is a solution however that is when creating a PDF, not an image.

Is there any way to stop Ghostscript from 'auto' rotating when converting to an image with Ghostscript arguments or do I have to modify the `pdf_main.ps` file to manually stop it rotating? If so, can anyone point me in the direction of what I'd need to change?

EDIT: A 'fix' for the above is to set the height and width to be the same value. That way, when ghostscript tries to fit the page, it uses the PDF orientation

Comment: @KJ I am using Ghostscript to convert the PDF here however

Comment: @KJ I’m not sure to be honest. These PDF files are uploaded and we take these uploaded files and generate a preview using Ghostscript so trimbox could be anything(?)

Comment: I can't look at it without an example file. -dAutoRotatePages, as you note, doesn't do anything with a rendering device, that only affects the pdfwrite device (PDF output). The FitPage option **always** rotates the page if it fits better that way, because it involves less scaling. You can, of course, write your own code to avoid that. If you look in pdf_main.ps, at around line 186 you will find the PostScript function NewPDF_FitPage, the very first thing it does is decide if it should rotate.  Stick "pop //false" at line 222 just ahead of the comment block "%% Store values..."

Comment: @KenS Sorry for my novice Postscript knowledge but, for postscript changes to take affect, do I need to do anything? I've edited the gs file like detailed above and ran the gs command I have in the question and I am seeing no difference in the output

Comment: @KenS I don't suppose you need to 'restart' ghostscript for the changes made to the `.ps` to take affect? I've tested this by completely deleting everything from my `pdf_main.ps` file and yet somehow, ghostscript still works, leading me to believe it's not using the updated version of the file

Comment: By default Ghostscript's resources are built into the executable in a ROM file system (linux packages vary in this regard, Windows are always built in). You either need to change the files and rebuild Ghostscript from source, or change the files and tell Ghostscript to use the changed files by 'Including' the path to the changed files, by using the -I switch.

Comment: @KenS Strange. I updated my `pdf_main.ps` file, and used the `-I` switch in my CLI command and I still did not see any change in my ghostscript result. I have a work around (see edit) that stops the image from being 'rotated' when using `FitPage`

Comment: -I on its own isn't enough,  you need -I=<path to modified resources> So if you modified /usr/local/bin/ghostpdl/Resource/pdf_main.ps you should use -I=/usr/local/bin/ghostpdl/Resource obviously your paths will vary.... If you get it wrong Ghostscript won't tell you, because the 'Include' just adds on to the existing paths. Assuming Ghostscript finds the files it needs **somewhere** (which it will if there is a ROM file system) then it will just use them and has no way to tell that the -I path you supplied is incorrect.

Comment: The 'optional' switch in PDF (I'm assuming you mean AutoRotatePages) is not the same at all, since it considers the dominant text orientation to derive the media orientation. There's a typo in my comment, you need to include Resource/Init, not just Resource.

Comment: @KJ I too came across that Command line message when running that command. I am a bit shocked that after X years, there is no switch in Ghostscript to stop it from auto rotating when creating an image from a PDF using the FitPage switch

Answer (score 1):

After trying to get Ghostscript to stop auto-rotating when using `-dFitPage`, and after I could not get the changes that @k-j and @kens gave me to work, I resorted to doing the following.

I set my height and width dimensions to be equal. This meant that not matter the orientation of the PDF, I could use the fit page switch and it would keep it's orientation.

This is because the `-dFitPage` switch rotates the PDF to best fit the dimensions with as little processing power as possible. Providing it with a square means that there should be no alternative orientation that fits the PDF better.

Tried and tested with multiple PDF's with varying heights and widths.

**EDIT: Not marking this question as resolved/ answered as this solution is more of a 'work around' rather than a potential answer but it does solve the rotating issue**